# Excel: How can I delete all rows except the fifth

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula

I have some Data in my Csv. file and I need to delete all rows except every 5th, how can I do that ?

[image]

Comment: You want to do this in excel or do you need a script in python to delete evertything?

Answer (score 3):

I'd advise you to load the CSV into PowerQuery. Though PQ by no means is my forte, I'd then take the following steps:

- Add an Index-Column with a starting index of '1' and a standard increment of '1';
- Add a custom column based on modulus 5, e.g.: `=Number.Mod([Index],5)=0`;
- Filter your custom column based on 'TRUE' values;
- Remove the index- & custom column.

For example:

[image: ![enter image description here]

- Add the index column:

[image]

- Add the custom column:

[image: ![enter image description here]

- Filter the custom column:

[image]

- Delete the index- and custom column:

[image]

- End up with only every 5th row:

[image]

---

For what it's worth, this is the m-code of me loading the data from my worksheet (source). You can load the data through CSV:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each Number.Mod([Index],5)=0),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Custom] = true)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Index", "Custom"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not-tested pseudo-code, but it will be something like that:

```
for i=end downto beginning:
  if mod(i,5) != 0 then 
    Range(i,1).EntireRow.Delete
  end if
 step -1
```

It is crucial to go from end to beginning, or you'll mess up the indexes in your rows :-)

Comment: Do you know what the ! exclamation mark means in VBA code?

Comment: @WeAreOne: it's not really VBA, it's pseudo-code which looks like VBA. By `!=` I mean `not equal to`.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a helper column with this formula:

```
=MOD(ROW(A2)-ROW($A$2)+1;5)
```

Replace semicolon with comma, if your Excel version needs.

ROW($A$2) is the first row of the data.

Then apply a filter
Data--> Filter

and remove the tick for the 0

Then delete rows.

then remove the filter

[image]

[image]

Delete sheet rows

[image]

Remove Filter

[image]

[image]

Remove helpercolumn

Then you can export the Excel file as csv.
Opening a csv in Excel, changing it and saving, might not work.